# Determining a confidence interval

Tags: probability, statistics

$p_m$ and $p_f$ are the respective proportions of male and female white-crowned sparrows that return to their hatching site. I've been asked to find the endpoints for a $95\%$ confidence interval for $p_m - p_f$ if $124$ out of $894$ males and $70$ out of $700$ females returned.

My attempt is as follows:

$p_m = 124/894 = 0.139$

$p_f = 70/100 = 0.1$

$Z = \frac{p_m - p_f}{\sqrt{(0.139)(1-0.139)/894+0.1(0.9)/700}} = 2.41$

given $\alpha = 0.05$, $|Z(0.025)| = 1.96$

Does this mean the ends of the interval are $(0.45,4.37)$?

Comment: If a proportion can only be between $0$ and $1$, then with $100\%$ confidence, we can assert that the difference of two proportions will be between $0 - 1 = -1$ and $1 - 0 = 1$.  So does it make sense to have a $95\%$ confidence interval that is $(0.45, 4.37)$?  What is a number like $4.37$ supposed to mean in such a context?

Comment: You need to specify the assumed distributions for your variables. They cannot be normally distributed (what the test you used assumes), since they must clearly be discrete and supported on $[0,N]$, not continuously on $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the null hypothesis that $p_m = p_f$, the quantity $Z$ should be roughly $N(0,1)$ by the central limit theorem. Therefore, under the null hypothesis, $P(-1.96 \leq Z \leq 1.96) = 0.95$. Changing your notation slightly to use $\hat{p}_m, \hat{p}_f$ for the maximum likelihood estimates of $p_m, p_f$, we have
$$P \left(-1.96 \leq \frac{\hat{p}_m - \hat{p}_f - (p_m - p_f)}{\sqrt{\hat{p}_m (1 - \hat{p}_m) / 894 + \hat{p}_f (1 - \hat{p}_f) / 700}} \leq1.96\right) = 0.95.$$
Rearranging this we obtain
$$P \left(\hat{p}_m - \hat{p}_f-1.96 s \leq p_m - p_f \leq \hat{p}_m - \hat{p}_f + 1.96 s \right) = 0.95,$$
where $s = \sqrt{\hat{p}_m (1 - \hat{p}_m) / 894 + \hat{p}_f (1 - \hat{p}_f) / 700}$.
So a rough 95% confidence interval is $[\hat{p}_m - \hat{p}_f-1.96 s, \hat{p}_m - \hat{p}_f+1.96 s],$ equal to $[0.00725, 0.0708]$ for $p_m - p_f$.

If you just wanted to test whether $p_m$ and $p_f$ are equal you would be best to use the likelihood ratio test, as in [this example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test#Coin_tossing).

Comment: thanks a lot for this thorough explanation and link to another example.